# Input type not working with enter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've made a chat but if I press the enter button the message won't send.
It will only send if I press the button.
This is the line for the input bar:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control chat-message" id="text-massage" 
       style="margin-left:0px;" maxlength="300"> <span class="input-group-btn">
```

This is the line for the SEND button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" 
        data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> WAIT..."
        id="send_massage" style="margin-right:0px;">SEND</button>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can we see the javascript you're using to handle the event?

Comment: Do you actually have a `<form>` tag around your input and button? Without it, the browser won't know what to do when you hit Enter.

Comment: Thanks. That was the issues. Dam I'm so bad... :c